# Is there a way to do a transactionscope around an entire testfixture (for all tests)?

Tags: c#, nunit, transactionscope

Basically instead of setting up data and then cleaning up in a NUnit test class. I want to do all my data inserts, run setup stored procedures etc, then rollback (cleanup) once all tests have run. Currently I am using a transactionscope in each and every test like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestName()
{
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
  {
    //run month end sproc
    //run select sprocs
    //do asserts       
  }
}
```

Comment: It is possible but I would not recommend it as test should be independent of each other, e.g., the data state should be the same before and after each test runs. Otherwise, data changed by one test could affect a subsequent test, and you cannot predict the order in which tests run.

Comment: I would like to run one stored procedure that changes a lot of data that is all dependent on each other, then in each test I run select procs (not changing data) which populates models which are only available in the scope of each test. After I have run all these tests, I want to rollback that proc in the start that changed everything. I am using an existing database with many dependencies and data that has to be in a specific state, so I am just altering the data with that proc in the start. Creating new setup data inserts etc for these tests would take to long.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I would not recommend it as test should be independent of each other, e.g., the data state should be the same before and after each test runs. Otherwise, data changed by one test could affect a subsequent test, and you cannot predict the order in which tests run

You also need to consider:

1. Transaction timeouts. If your tests take a long time (which may be unpredictable), the "global" transaction could easily timeout.
2. Transaction locking. The data changes at the start of the transaction will create locks which may affect the later selects and invalidate your tests.
3. You should be simulating the transaction state of "live" operation, which I assume will not include an enclosing "global" transaction which has made a bunch of data changes.

Alternatives:

Use a transaction in the test-run initialisation to set up the data, and then in the test-run clean-up use another transaction to revert the data changes. Neither transaction should span the actual tests.

Or: back up the database in the test-run initialisation, and make the data changes. Restore the database back up in the test-run clean up.

Or: mock the database (probably a lot of work!).

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit your tester class from AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests (Spring.NET)

Checkout "**16.3.2. Dependency Injection of test fixtures**" from "http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html"

Also, in TestFixtureSetUp you can create the schema of your Database and on TestFixtureTearDown you can remove the schema.